# db.collection.find() does not work in EclipseLink's native query

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipselink, nosql

I am using EclipseLink NoSQL for my project. One strange thing I encounter is that when using native query "db.collection.findOne()" things work perfectly while "db.collection.find()" throws me an exception.

This piece of code works:

```
Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery("db.EMPLOYEE.findOne()", Employee.class);
List employees = emQuery.getResultList();
```

And I have

```
[EL Fine]: 2014-07-16 11:55:05.78--ServerSession(1394835)--Connection(17102354)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Executing QueryStringInteraction()
    spec => null
    query => db.EMPLOYEE.findOne()
    parameters => []
[EL Finest]: 2014-07-16 11:55:05.806--ServerSession(1394835)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Adapter result: {RFID=12435, VERSION=1, _id=53B632034390846204F1A165, EMPLOYEEID=Smith, BADGENO=2487, ADDUPDATEDDATE=Fri Jul 04 12:48:03 SGT 2014, ADDUPDATEDBY=Alex, TYPE=MANAGER}
```

While

```
Query emQuery = em.createNativeQuery("db.EMPLOYEE.find()", Employee.class);
List employees = emQuery.getResultList();
```

returns me this

```
[EL Fine]: 2014-07-16 11:59:26.688--ServerSession(2940862)--Connection(24410159)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Executing QueryStringInteraction()
    spec => null
    query => db.EMPLOYEE.find()
    parameters => []
[EL Finest]: 2014-07-16 11:59:26.731--ServerSession(2940862)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Adapter result: {value=DBQuery: testfloor.EMPLOYEE -> undefined}
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [EISMappedRecord(
    value => DBQuery: testfloor.EMPLOYEE -> undefined)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employee )
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

i had same error when i used find() method in native query but i use a workaround, first of all you must use native queries and aggregate of mongodb and save the result in a temporary collection then you can use a simple Named Query for findAll. with this Technic you can do all arbitrary queries in mongodb and send the result to a Session Bean in java

Answer (score 0):

One of the items in the collection does not have a value for the property defined as the primary in the `Employee` class.
`findOne()` works because it returns the first item found and that probably has a value for the primary key. Whereas, in the case of `find()`, all items from the collection are returned along with the one that does not have a value for the primary key. When EclipseLink tries to convert the record to an instance of `Employee`, it fails because of missing primary key.

Comment: So I did these 2 test cases: First I remove all the records inside the Employee collection and add just one new record with all the values assigned to its corresponding properties and make sure no field is empty/null. find() still fails while findOne() works. Second test case is I purposely leave one field empty/null. And I get the same result. find() still fails while findOne() works.